# Calculate SNR in a B&W image

Tags: image-processing, snr

How to calculate the SNR of an image with only black (0,0,0) and white (255,255,255) pixels?

For example, the 20x20 image below has 39 black pixels. Some noise pixels are added (black pixels at A, B, C and D; white pixels at E, F, G, H).

[image: Original image]
[image: Noise added]

I calculated the power of the original image as below:

$N = 20\times20 = 400$

$P_{image} = \mu_{image} = \frac{39\cdot0+(400-39)\cdot255}{400}=230.1375$

But I'm not sure about the calculation of of $P_{noise}$:

$N_{white \ pixels} = 400-39+E,F,G-A,B,C = 361$

$N_{black \ pixels} = 39+A,B,C-E,F,G = 39$

$P_{noise} = \sigma_{image} = \sqrt{\frac{(255-\mu_{image})^2\cdot N_{white \ pixels}+(0-\mu_{image})^2\cdot N_{black \ pixels}}{400}}=75.6425$

$SNR = 10\cdot log{\frac{P_{image}}{P_{noise}}} = 4.832dB$

Does the calculation make sense? Because in an extreme case, where there are 39 white noise pixels overlapping entirely on the black pixels, the entire image becomes white and loss all the original information. But the SNR actually goes up based on my calculation above.